# how to check response from other function before completing python function

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am pretty new to Python and backend development in general.  I am writing an email handler to take inquiries from a form and save the user's information to an email list DB for later marketing purposes, save the message to another DB that stores incoming messages, and send an email to the admin notifying of a new form submission.  Everything is working fine except if an invalid email or phone number are sent to the EmailListManager, the RecievedMessagesManager does not receive the response and continues with the rest of the function.  I have my front end (Angular) set to handle a response error, but it only sees the response from RecievedMessagesManager.  If the data is not valid for the EmailListManager I want it to stop the execution of the RecievedMessagesManager and return false.  This is what I have:

```
@staticmethod
def Create(createData):
    """
    Creates a message with specified data, stores email to email list, and sends email notification to administrator.

    """
    print ('create')
    if 'label' in createData:
        createData['label'] = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', createData['label'])
            
    serializer = RecievedMessagesSerializer(None, data=createData)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        EmailListManager.Create(createData)
        created = RecievedMessagesSerializer(serializer.save())
        RecievedMessagesManager.SendVerificationEmail(createData['name'], createData['email'], createData['subject'], createData['inquiry'])
        return (True, created.data,)
    else:
        return (False, serializer.errors,)
```

Comment: can't you simply make `EmailListManager.Create(createData)` e.g. return True or False depending on whether it succeeded or not, and then use that to either continue the execution or return an error?

Comment: It does, how do I listen to that response data in the function above?

Comment: the same way you already get 'created' from ReceivedMessagesSerializer, just assign the return value to a variable. i figured the code is clearer in an answer so wrote it there

Answer (score 0):

Given you validate the email address inside EmailListManager.Create, just make it return True or False depending on whether the address was valid, and use that info in your flow:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    valid_email = EmailListManager.Create(createData)
    if valid_email:
        created = RecievedMessagesSerializer(serializer.save())
        RecievedMessagesManager.SendVerificationEmail(createData['name'], createData['email'], createData['subject'], createData['inquiry'])
        return (True, created.data,)
    else:
        return (False, 'invalid email error somehow')
else:
    return (False, serializer.errors,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up importing the EmailListSerializer to check:

```
serializer = RecievedMessagesSerializer(None, data=createData)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializeEmailInfo = EmailListSerializer(None, data=createData)
        if serializeEmailInfo.is_valid():
            EmailListManager.Create(createData)
            created = RecievedMessagesSerializer(serializer.save())
            RecievedMessagesManager.SendVerificationEmail(createData['name'], createData['email'], createData['subject'], createData['inquiry'])
            return (True, created.data,)
        else:
            return (False, serializer.errors,)
    else:
        return (False, serializer.errors,)
```

Hope this helps other folks.